# Change the default route from / to /docuseal/

Tags: django, nginx, ruby-on-rails-4

I don’t know if it’s the good section but my problem is the following one :

In my VM, I have a django server running with gunicorn and nginx and I would like to add a docuseal entity running with ruby on rails on the website (docuseal is also running with nginx). In fact, I figure out how to make my nginx configuration. So I can access docuseal by the url mydomaine/docuseal/, all the other are manage by django.

However, all the route in my docuseal app start with ‘/’, but as I say, it’s django part. So I would like to “shift” all the docuseal routes from “/…” to “/docuseal/…”. I tried to make change in config/routes.rb but I didn’t succeed.

Can somebody help me please.

Thanks you !

Comment: What did you try and why didn't it succeed?  Have you looked at how [namespaces](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#controller-namespaces-and-routing) worker?

Comment: Honestly, I'm totally new to ruby ​​on rails. I'm just trying to manipulate a fully built application.
I tried to use scope but I think I didn't quite understand how to do it: Do I have to scope each "resources: " line?

Comment: Try wrapping all of the resources within a `namespace :docuseal do` block.

Comment: I don't know where to writte it exactly because the application is a bit complicate for a beginner i guess
Here is the full code https://github.com/docusealco/docuseal/blob/master/config/routes.rb

Comment: Try to put some example code of what you've tried in your question.  Check out the docs on [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [on-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) questions.  You'll be more likely to get answers if you ask a focused question, try to provide a [minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), and include the code you've tried in the question.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the following nginx configuration to shift all the docuseal routes from / to /docuseal/:

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name mydomaine;

  location / {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000;
  }

  location /docuseal/ {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000;
  }
}
```

The first location block will proxy all requests to the Django server on port 8000. The second location block will proxy all requests to the docuseal server on port 3000.

To make sure that this works, you need to make sure that the docuseal server is listening on port 3000. You can do this by editing the docuseal configuration file, `config/routes.rb`. In this file, you need to add the following line:

```
mount '/docuseal/', to: 'docuseal#index', as: 'docuseal'
```

This will tell the docuseal server to listen on port 3000 for requests that start with `/docuseal/`.

Once you have made these changes, you need to restart the nginx and docuseal servers. You can do this by running the following commands:

```
sudo service nginx restart
sudo service docuseal restart
```

After the servers have restarted, you should be able to access `docuseal` by visiting the URL `mydomaine/docuseal/`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/gpt-policy